# Getting json array to create products index problems using Php, json, JS and JSON

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax, json

Having a few problems creating a products index.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're pushing down html as well in the `products.php` page. Make sure the output of the php that you're retrieving from only returns JSON.

Also, check the syntax on your script:

```
$.get({
  type: "GET",
  url: "products2.php",
  data: 'id=' + userid,
  dataType: "json",
  success: function (data) {
    document.getElementById("name").innerHTML = data[0];
    document.getElementById("decription").innerHTML = data[1];
    document.getElementById("price").innerHTML = data[2];
    document.getElementById("stock").innerHTML = data[3];
  }
});
```

You were using `$rows` but attempting to access `data`. Adding a simple `console.log(data);` in the success function will dump the results to the console in chrome/firefox so you can see what is being returned. (Be sure to check the network tab as well, as it can give you some tips as to why the data isn't being properly fetched.)

Answer (score 0):

I've done something similar and this worked fine for me:

```
<?php
$array['status'] = 0;
...
echo json_encode($array);
```

Populate the array with whatever you need.

And then:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "type",
    url: "url",
    data: {
        data: data
    },
    success: function (data) {
        console.log(data.status);
    }
});
```